# In which region of diode breakdown starts?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

i confused about in which region of a diode breakdown start,

in some books it is given that breakdown starts in depletion region but in some other is said that it start in p-side or n-side of diode (not mentioned as depletion region).

Answer (score 2):

There are two common forms of breakdown with different mechanisms.

[Zener breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_effect) happens when the depletion region gets narrow enough that carriers from outside the depletion region can tunnel across it. This is probably what you read about when it said that breakdown starts with carriers from the n or p regions.

[Avalanche breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_breakdown) happens when carriers traversing the depletion region "knocks" other bound carriers free, leading to current multiplication. This can start with a carrier pair spontaneously generated in the active region by thermal effects or background EM radiation. It is probably what you read about when it said that breakdown starts in the depletion region.

Comment: What is the role high electric field in depletion region in zener diode

Comment: @teja, that's beyond the scope of the question that was asked. Probably the answer is in the Wiki article I linked to. If you don't find the answer there, you can post a new question to ask for further explanation.